# fetch api is not giving result properly in react but works fine with postman

Tags: react-hooks, axios, rendering, fetch-api, mern

fetch api is not giving result properly

So i am making a chatting app where all user's info is stored in backend.
That is working properly on postman but when i try to console log 'fetchChat' method then it shows undefined but after i reload the page error is gone and i get desired output.

Also when i try to log inside getChatDetails() i get error {Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')} but again when i reload all things get rendered properly.

i want to render these things without reloading and without ny initial errors.

```
import { Box, Button, Stack, Text, useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ChatState } from "../context/ChatProvider";
import axios from "axios";
import SearchUserLoading from "../LoadingState/SearchUserLoading";
import { AddIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

const MyChats = () => {

    const {
        user,
        setUser,
        selectedChat,
        setSelectedChat,
        chats,
        setChats,
        clicked,
        setClicked,
    } = ChatState();

    const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const toast = useToast();

    const fetchChat = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
                }
            };
            const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/chat", config);
            setLoading(false);
            setChats(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            toast({
                title: "Error  Fetching chats",
                description: error,
                status: "error",
                duration: 2000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: "top-left",
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoggedUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
        fetchChat();
    }, []);

    const getChatDetails = (loggedUser, chatUsers) => {
        console.log(chatUsers[0]);
    };

    return (

        <Box
            d={{ base: selectedChat ? "none" : "flex", md: "flex" }}
            flexDir="column"
            alignItems="center"
            p={3}
            bg="white"
            w={{ base: "100%", md: "31%" }}
            borderRadius="lg"
            borderWidth="1px"
        >
            <Box
                key={v4()}
                pb={3}
                px={3}
                fontSize={{ base: "28px", md: "30px" }}
                fontFamily="Work sans"
                d="flex"
                w="100%"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
            >
                My Chats
                <Button
                    d="flex"
                    fontSize={{ base: "17px", md: "10px", lg: "17px" }}
                    rightIcon={<AddIcon />}
                >
                    New Group Chat
                </Button>
            </Box>
            <Box
                d="flex"
                flexDir="column"
                p={3}
                bg="#F8F8F8"
                w="100%"
                h="100%"
                borderRadius="lg"
                overflowY="hidden"
            >
                {chats ? (
                    <Stack overflowY="scroll">
                        {chats.map((chat) => (
                            <Box
                                onClick={() => setSelectedChat(chat)}
                                cursor="pointer"
                                bg={selectedChat === chat ? "#38B2AC" : "#E8E8E8"}
                                color={selectedChat === chat ? "white" : "black"}
                                px={3}
                                py={2}
                                borderRadius="lg"
                                key={chat._id}
                            >
                                <Text>
                                    {!chat.isGroupChat
                                        ? getChatDetails(loggedUser, chat.users)
                                        : chat.chatName}
                                </Text>
                                {chat.latestMessage && (
                                    <Text fontSize="xs">
                                        <b>{chat.latestMessage.sender.name} : </b>
                                        {chat.latestMessage.content.length > 50
                                            ? chat.latestMessage.content.substring(0, 51) + "..."
                                            : chat.latestMessage.content}
                                    </Text>
                                )}
                            </Box>
                        ))}
                    </Stack>
                ) : (
                    <SearchUserLoading />
                )}
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default MyChats;
```

Also below is snippet of axios.post which is posting data to Chats.
This post is executing before axios.get()

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  Avatar,
  Box,
  Button,
  Drawer,
  DrawerBody,
  DrawerCloseButton,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerFooter,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerOverlay,
  Input,
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
  MenuDivider,
  MenuItem,
  MenuList,
  Text,
  Tooltip,
  useToast,
  useDisclosure,
  Spinner,
} from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { BellIcon, ChevronDownIcon, Search2Icon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import { ChatState } from "../context/ChatProvider";
import ProfileModal from "./ProfileModal.jsx";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import SearchUserLoading from "../LoadingState/SearchUserLoading.jsx";
import ChatSearchedNames from "./ChatSearchedNames.jsx";

const SideDrawer = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [searchResult, setSearchedResult] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [loadingChats, setLoadingChats] = useState(false);

  const {
    user,
    setUser,
    selectedChat,
    setSelectedChat,
    chats,
    setChats,
    clicked,
    setClicked,
  } = ChatState();
  const history = useHistory();
  const toast = useToast();

  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();

  const logoutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    history.push("/");
  };

  const handleSearch = async () => {
    if (!search) {
      toast({
        title: "No name was entered",
        description: "Please enter a name or email to search user",
        status: "warning",
        duration: 2000,
        isClosable: true,
        position: "top-left",
      });
    } else {
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const config = { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` } };

        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3000/user?search=${search}`,
          config
        );

        setSearchedResult(data);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        toast({
          title: "Error Searching User",
          description: error,
          status: "error",
          duration: 2000,
          isClosable: true,
          position: "top-left",
        });
      }
    }
  };

  const acessChat = async (userId) => {
    try {
      setLoadingChats(true);
      setClicked(!clicked);
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        },
      };
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:3000/chat`,
        { userId },
        config
      );

      if (!chats.find((c) => c._id === data._id)) {
        const newData = await setChats([data, ...chats]);
      }
      setSelectedChat(data);
      setLoadingChats(false);
      onClose();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      toast({
        title: "Error fetching the chat",
        description: error.message,
        status: "error",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
        position: "bottom-left",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="space-between" // Corrected property name
        alignItems="center"
        w="100%"
        h="10%"
        bg="white"
        p={3}
        marginTop={3}
      >
        <Tooltip label="search users for chat" hasArrow>
          <Button variant={"ghost"} onClick={onOpen}>
            <Search2Icon boxSize={6} />
            <Text p={4}> Search User</Text>
          </Button>
        </Tooltip>

        <Text fontSize={"2xl"} fontFamily={"cursive"}>
          Rendevous-ChatApp
        </Text>

        <Box>
          <Menu>
            <MenuButton paddingRight={3}>
              <BellIcon boxSize={6} />
            </MenuButton>
            <MenuList>
              <MenuItem>We have to add this funtionality</MenuItem>
            </MenuList>
          </Menu>

          <Menu>
            <MenuButton>
              <Avatar size={"sm"} cursor={"pointer"} name={user.name}></Avatar>
            </MenuButton>
            <MenuList>
              <ProfileModal>
                <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
              </ProfileModal>
              <MenuDivider />
              <MenuItem onClick={logoutHandler}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </MenuList>
          </Menu>
        </Box>
      </Box>

      {/* search drawer */}

      <Drawer isOpen={isOpen} placement="left" onClose={onClose}>
        <DrawerOverlay />
        <DrawerContent>
          <DrawerCloseButton />
          <DrawerHeader>Search User</DrawerHeader>

          <DrawerBody>
            <Box display={"flex"}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Type here..."
                value={search}
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
              />
              <Button ml={3} isLoading={isLoading} onClick={handleSearch}>
                Search
              </Button>
            </Box>
            {isLoading ? (
              <SearchUserLoading /> //this is a compoent that we made for loading names
            ) : (
              searchResult.map((result) => {
                return (
                  <ChatSearchedNames //this is a component that we made in miscellenious
                    key={result._id} //for showing results of chat searches
                    userName={result.name}
                    userEmail={result.email}
                    handleFunction={() => acessChat(result._id)}
                  />
                );
              })
            )}
            {loadingChats && <Spinner ml={20} size={"xl"} />}
          </DrawerBody>

          <DrawerFooter>
            <Button variant="outline" mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </DrawerFooter>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideDrawer;
```

Comment: can you share your "chats" data example?